# How can we remove some colorscale/numbers from "Show points of gridded data source" Azure map?

Tags: maps, azure-maps

Currently, we are implementing azure Show points of gridded data source map. Below so the link for the same.

https://samples.azuremaps.com/?sample=show-points-of-gridded-data-source

Here, we want to **exclude **few colors and values. **See the below screenshot**.

Comment: Posted here as well : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1133685/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Simply update the number to color mapping in the `colorScale` variable. Ensure the numbers align with the values in the property you are binding to in the data. For example, if you are working with numbers between 0 and 1, you would likely want a decimal scale. In the sample the scale is from <25 to 100+ and looks like this:

```
var colorScale = [
            25, '#73ffdc',
            50, '#f9ffb9',
            75, '#ffb849',
            100, '#ca0056'
        ];
```

If this scale works, but you just want less steps (colors), simply remove/edit/add what evey you want such that the numbers increase. For example, if you want a scale of <5 to 10+ with just two colors, the variable could look like this:

```
var colorScaler = {
   5, '#ffb849',
   10, '#ca0056'
];
```